# How to make Django models not prepend the app's name to the model if the model name is the app name?

Tags: python, django, models, django-syncdb, syncdb

So here's what's happening:

I start an app called `cars` and create a model called `Cars`. When I `syncdb`, it creates the table `cars_cars`. How do I make it so that it just create the table `cars`?

Also, to add to it, what if I have an app called `cars` and have a model called `car`, but want the table to be created for that model be called `cars`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's what [`Meta.db_table`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#db-table) is for.